# C++ Sorting vector of structs alphabetically

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, struct

I have this record management program I am building for an introductory programming course. Part of the code is the function `sortEmail` which is supposed to sort the vector recordList alphabetically and calls the `sortAlphabet` function. I'm getting an error on this line:`sort(recordList.begin(), recordList.end(), compareAlphabet);` that "sort was not declared in this scope." How can I fix this?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
struct Record
{
    string name;
    string email;
};

bool compareAlphabet(const Record& a, const Record& b)
{
    return a.name < b.name;
}

sortEmail(vector<Record>& recordList)
{
    system("cls");
    sort(recordList.begin(), recordList.end(), compareAlphabet);
    cout<<"Name have been sorted alphabetically"<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i!=recordList.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<recordList[i].name<<endl;
        cout<<recordList[i].email<<endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    system("cls");  
}
```

Comment: Can you trim the code to just what's needed to replicate the problem?

Comment: I suggest reading some documentation for the `sort` function you're trying to call. And reduce your code to a [mcve].

Comment: I'll do that! Code trimmed down as well :)

Comment: Add `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: Thank you, and also I didn't put `void` in front of `sortEmail(vector<Record>& recordList)`  ...'facepalm'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to include `<algorithm>`
Add `#include <algorithm>` and see if it works.

Comment: Yup, and forgot `void` in front of `sortEmail(vector<Record>& recordList)` as well...